# Python's argparse mutually exclusive options

Tags: python, argparse

I'm looking to implement an mutually exclusive group, however If a specific option is set it will require further parameters. Where as the other option (which will be defaul) requires no further parameters to be set.

Is there a way to configure this? I cant seem to find this specific scenario on googles or stackoverflow.

Example of options

```
link_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group('Argument Group', 'Specify specific arguments')
link_group.add_argument('-la', '--linka', help='Specify active Link, this requires two additional parameters', required=True, action='store_true')
link_group.add_argument('-lp', '--linkp', help='Specify passive Link, this does not require addition parameters', required=True, action='store_true')
link_group.add_argument('-lau', '--linkUser', help='Specify Link Username', required=True)
link_group.add_argument('-lap', '--linkPass', help='Specify Link Password', required=True)
```

Comment: Why not include all info in a single parameter? `-l www.link.com:user:pw`

Comment: Arr yes thats an option, no doubt it will cause problems for users but I think thats a viable work around if I cant find an answer. Thanks

Comment: It would also not be unusual to query the user for name and password during runtime, which means it would not be a required parameter in the argument parser.

Comment: Yes I did think about that but as this is a term based application it will be displayed. I did also think of an encrypted config file for credentails but I think its overkill in this instance.

Comment: Can't you test for the added parameters after parsing?  Your users won't know the difference.  Have you thought about how you would indicate such a requirement in the `usage`?  Marking complicated logical requirements in `usage` is a difficult task.

Comment: Yes I have, I am most likley going to go down the custom formatter and manual describer. `argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='AppName', formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter(prog,max_help_position=50), usage=descriptor_.des())`